# Solr Facet Group Query Filtering

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

There is about 12 million solr data as shown in the model below. I want to group emotion values ​​using solr facet query structure and find the total number of values, how can I do?

```
<doc>
<str name="id">389352936</str>
<str name="title">Title</str>
<str name="body">Body</str>
<date name="feeddate">2019-05-05T09:22:46Z</date>
<int name="sentiment">0</int>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">389352937</str>
<str name="title">Title</str>
<str name="body">Body</str>
<date name="feeddate">2019-05-06T09:22:46Z</date>
<int name="sentiment">1</int>
</doc>
```

result  structure i want

```
[
{"feeddate":"2019-05-05T00:00:00Z","sentiment":{"0":10,"1":20,"2":30}},{"feeddate":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","sentiment":{"0":5,"1":10,"2":15}},,{"feeddate":"2019-05-07T00:00:00Z","sentiment":{"0":12,"1":21,"2":12}}
]
```

I'm trying the query below but it's not in the structure I want

```
facet.range={!tag=rdt}feeddate
&facet.range.start=2019-01-01T00:00:00Z
&facet.sort=feeddate
&facet.field=sentiment
&facet.range.end=2019-02-01T00:00:00Z
&facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY&facet=true
&facet.pivot={!range=piv1}sentiment
```

Return data

```
[ {field:"sentiment",value:0,count:6258160,ranges:{feeddate:{counts:["2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",7983,"2019-01-02T00:00:00Z",9673,"2019-01-03T00:00:00Z",12727,"2019-01-04T00:00:00Z"]}}, 
            {field:"sentiment",value:1,count:1830481,ranges:{feeddate:{counts:["2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",4983,"2019-01-02T00:00:00Z",9673,"2019-01-03T00:00:00Z",23727,"2019-01-04T00:00:00Z"]}}
            {field:"sentiment",value:2,count:3086818,ranges:{feeddate:{counts:["2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",3983,"2019-01-02T00:00:00Z",9673,"2019-01-03T00:00:00Z",10727,"2019-01-04T00:00:00Z"]}}
]
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the structure being returned? Is it just the returned form, or is the content wrong? What is wrong?

Comment: @MatsLindh, no error. Just how can I get the result in the format I want. I added the result

Comment: So your goal is to make "feeddate" the root element instead, and then have the sentiment counts as the pivot beneath that? I don't think trying to get an exact JSON response is what you should be concerned about first, but get the pivot hierarchy to be correct.

Comment: @MatsLindh, Yes, the feeddate must be root and I want to group emotion values ​​in feeddate. It should be as follows {"feeddate" :"2019-05-05T00:00:00Z", "sentiment": {"0": 10, "1": 20, "2": 30}}